# ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework or DAL class and AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was used to developing web apps in WebForms, and now I'm switching to MVC.

I am able to create a simple project and then connect it with an **Oracle** DB using **Entity Framework** (Code First approach).

I was used to writing my DAL class and do manual queries to the database, however I'd like to use **Entity Framework** with complex queries.

How could I implement AngularJS in that project?

Thank you

My knowledge covers:
HTML, CSS (SASS), Razor, a bit of jQuery, MVC model, basic Entity Framework, Telerik UI for ASP.NET Ajax, Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC (Kendo UI with MVC wrappers), bootstrap.

What should I learn next to fully develop an **Admin Dashboard** template containing grids, charts and controllers based on real database records?

Answer (score 1):

I have gone your path and here are some thoughts.

You have in front of you a lot to dive into. To name the most important:

- ASP.NET MVC / WEB API
- Front End
- ORM

DO NOT try to invade all these areas from the beginning.

Focus first on learning plain ASP.NET MVC and leave Entity Framework outside. Use a micro-ORM (i suggest [DAPPER](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)) and THEN move on to EF.

On the frontend world dont go to Angular just yet. Focus on using ASP.NET MVC with standard views and add some JQuery to start moving....

There are a lot of technologies that  you need to learn and going to all of them directly you will be wasted. Go slowly and try to unerstand why dapper is no longer for you and you need EF. try to understand why Jquery should be replaced with KnockoutJS or Angular or whatever JS framework.

It may seem to you that this approach is unnecessary but i highly doubt it as it will leave you with distinct knowledge on various areas that are bound to change all the time in the future.

*There is no such thing as a "proper" way to develop in the web today...*

**AFTER YOUR UPDATE**:

You can use standard ASP.NET MVC and have model binding between roundtrips with Standard MVC Views and Razor.

If you need to move to Ajax world then of course angular is an option , but you could also consider using knockoutJS for form binding. It depends on your project size.

Also if you care about changing DB in the future going to a DB that EF doesnt support you could consider micro-ORMs (dapper) or Nhibernate.

Comment: Thank you, but i think I need to explain my experience better.
I know how to create a basic MVC project and I am used to CSS (SASS, exactly) and HTML, and a tiny bit of jQuery to make some nice animations etc. so no problem to develop a nice UI. Fact is, i can have a nice UI but I need to bind every control (a grid, eg.) to a database Table, and I tought it could be done in Angular

Comment: Ok, Update your question and i will revise my answer. Of course what i say depends on the level of expertise to all these technologies.

Comment: Angular moves the responsibility of ui binding to JS. You can achieve this in ASP.MVC with model binding and standard views. If you need to make it through AJAX you could try KNOCKOUT instead of full fledge JS framework like angular

Comment: Yeah I am currently using Telerik's Kendo UI for MVC to bind my data to a grid, for example, parsing the data to Json and passing it to the relative grid, bound in Ajax mode.
What could be the difference if I use Angular or Knockout, how could I post the changes made to the grid back to the db?

Comment: Thats my point..Since you are changing approach...dump third party controls , learn knockout / angular from scratch using jquery/bootstrap. there is a whole new game, that you cant approach with webforms logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your read some about Entity framework  for instance this blog post [EF pros and cons](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bnaya/2013/01/13/entity-framework-pro-and-con/).

By experience I can say , EF is nice to work with but has quite some problems , one of them is performance issues.

Comment: I don't think this will be a problem since I won't be using that on very large DBs or projects

Comment: well a small database is also slower with ef , but if it doesn't matter and a short development time is crucial  then I would definitely go for EF using code first.